# Encrypt video with CryptoJS, store it in Firebase and watch it decrypted in HTML5 video

Tags: angularjs, firebase, html5-video, firebase-storage, cryptojs

I'm trying to encrypt a video using the CryptoJS library. The goal is to encrypt it and store it in Firebase Storage. Later, when you want to visualize, it is decrypted and added as an url to the HTML video tag. I can't get the video displayed after decrypting it, any idea of what the problem is?  I have the feeling that the problem is with treating the output of the cipher as a string. I don't know in what way I should treat it so that it continues to maintain the properties of a video file. Thanks in advance.

The current code is:

```
    //Encrypt and upload function
    function almacenarFicheroGrabacionVideo(file) {
        let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('videos/' + file.name);
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {
          let read = reader.result;
          let task = storageRef.putString(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(read, getCookie('key')).toString());
          task.on('state_changed', function progress(snapshot) {
          }, function error(err) {
            console.log(err);
          }, function complete() {
            console.log("fichero subido");
          });
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
      }

//Decrypt and visualize video
  $scope.verVideo = function() {
    firebase.storage().ref('videos/').child('Blurred Bokeh Video 2.mp4').getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
      fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.blob()) // Gets the response and returns it as a blob
        .then(blob => {
          let reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function () {
            let fileDown = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(reader.result, getCookie('clave')).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
            var videoNode = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
            let blob = new Blob([fileDown], {type: "video/mp4"});
            let url  = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            let element = document.createElement('a');
            element.setAttribute('href', url);
            element.setAttribute('download', 'Blurred Bokeh Video 2.mp4');
            element.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(element);
            element.click();
            document.body.removeChild(element);
          };
          reader.readAsText(blob);
        });
    }).catch(function (error) {
      // Handle any errors
      console.log(error);
    });
  };
```